# ExtJS MVC form references

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm new to Sencha ExtJS. I've just started creating a MVC application. Currently I'm trying to create a login screen for that application, but I can't get reference to my login form from login controller. Here is my code:

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fleximanager',

    requires: [
    ],

    controllers: [
        'Login'
    ],

    autoCreateViewport: true,

    init: function() {
    }
});
```

Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('Fleximanager.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Fleximanager.view.login.Flexilogin'
    ],
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype:'flexilogin'
    }]
});
```

Flexilogin.js

```
Ext.define('Fleximanager.view.login.Flexilogin', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'flexilogin',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    },

    id: 'flexilogin',
    style: {background: '#8fc33a'},
    items: [{
        xtype:'panel',
        title: 'Login',
        frame: true,
        width: 350,
        height: 200,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {
            layout: 'anchor',
            id: 'flexiloginform',
            bodyPadding: 15,

            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                name: 'username',
                allowBlank: false
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'password',
                inputType: 'password',
                allowBlank: false
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Register',
                id: 'registerbtn',
                action: 'register'
            },{
                text: 'Login',
                id: 'loginbtn',
                formBind: true,
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

and the controller's Login.js

```
Ext.define('Fleximanager.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        'Fleximanager.view.login.Flexilogin',
    ],
    refs:[{
        ref: 'loginbtn',
        selector: '#loginbtn'
    }],

    init: function(){
        this.control({
            'loginbtn': {
                'click': function(){
                    console.log('click');
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

The code is supposed to log 'click' to console after you click the login button, but it does nothing. Can anyone help me?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you are referencing the button.

```
refs:[{
    ref: 'loginbtn',
    selector: '#loginbtn'
}],
```

Is creating a reference getter method `this.getLoginbtn` to use in the controller, but it cannot be used in `this.control`

The string key in `this.control` is a identifier like defined in [`Ext.ComponentQuery.query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery). It searches for xtype/alias and itemId.

```
this.control({
    'flexilogin #loginbtn': {
     ^ xtype     ^ itemId
```

Note that you should use `itemId` instead of `id` because `id` must be unique on the page at any moment, `itemId` should be unique inside a component; change like this:

```
{
      text: 'Login',
      itemId: 'loginbtn',
      ^ replace id by itemId
      formBind: true,
      name: 'login'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give a name to your button like this,

```
{
      text: 'Login',
      id: 'loginbtn',
      formBind: true,
      name: 'login'
}
```

and now in controller, put this code:

```
this.control({
            'button[name="login"]': {
                click: function(){
                    console.log('click');
                }
            }
        })
```

This will serve your purpose.